# Is a person endangering others always* a Rodef?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, rodef

Does a person endangering others inherently* have a Din of a [Rodef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodef)?

Related: [Is a speeding driver who causes damage exempt from paying due to his status as a Roidef?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18518/5)

*Leave aside for purposes of the question someone acting out orders of a proper Beith Din or a soldier in combat.

Comment: How specific are you looking for? Like what if I hold two guns at two people and only one is loaded but I don't know which one. Is that a specific target?

Comment: Also, how do you mean "target" - does that require intent?  If so, neither a mosquito nor a fetus cannot be considered a rodef.

Comment: DoubleAA and @CharlesKoppelman, clearer now?

Comment: yup, much clearer

Comment: @SethJ "inherently" as opposed to what?

Comment: @msh210 As opposed to it depending on additional criteria. Does being a danger make a person a Rodef?

Answer (score 3):

The Gemoro in Sanhedrin says even a fetus can be considered a Roidef to its mother, so we see that without intent one is still a Roidef. We can also assume that not every Roidef that chases would win the fight and nevertheless forfeits his life just by trying. There is no Halacha that if he only has a 25% chance of killing his victim he is not a Roidef, so we see there is no need of certainty of fatality to the victim.

Comment: Every fetus is a danger to its mother, so we see that it _is_ s matter of degree of danger or likelihood of fatality.

Comment: @SethJ that fetus was brought to bring proof for killing without intent. Read again

Comment: I'm aware of the Gemara. But your conclusion is faulty. If the Colorado theater shooter had fired a single round instead of hundreds, would he have been a Rodef?  What if he had not fired the gun at all?  Would having it there and looking like he was going to fire make him a Rodef?  What if someone is celebrating July 4th by shooting his gun in the air?  What goes up must come down, and [people have been hit by stray bullets fired into the air](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celebratory_gunfire#Falling-bullet_injuries).  Does that mean someone who fires the bullets into the air is a Rodef?

Comment: @sethj one may kill a roidef if there is legitimate reason to suspect a chance of danger. Once he has din Roidef he may be killed. whats so hard to understand?

Comment: I don't have a problem understanding the Din. I'm questioning your conclusion that "There is no Halacha that if he only has a 25% chance of killing his victim he is not a Roidef, so we see there is no need of certainty of fatality to the victim."  Clearly there must be some reasonable expectation that the threat is grave, otherwise any fetus would be a Rodef, as would any driver of any car, and anyone holding a kitchen knife, even if he is currently engaged in chopping a carrot - because he _might_ decide to turn it on someone.

Comment: @sethj oh now i get it, you mean what percentage of danger does there have to be

Comment: There are other aspects to consider, but yes, that's a big part of my question.